# HTTP to HTTPS and 301 redirect chains on Magento

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, redirect

We have successfully moved from `HTTP` to `HTTPS`, and now got some redirect chains. We want to do the following, directly:

1. From http ://domain.tld to https ://www.domain.tld
2. From http ://domain.tld/subdir/ to https ://www.domain.tld/subdir/

Right now, www is added first, then again `301` to `HTTPS`, like this:

1. http ://domain.tld => http ://www.domain.tld => https ://www.domain.tld
2. http ://domain.tld/subdir/ => http ://www.domain.tld/subdir/ => https ://www.domain.tld/subdir/

Also, if possible, all the other domains on the server (Magento stores), should not be able to use HTTPS, and should be redirected back to HTTPS only.

Thanks,

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
SetEnvIf SERVER_PORT 443 HTTPS=on
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

// DEFAULT //  
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex index.php


// REDIRECT ALL TO HTTPS //
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.domain\.tld [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L] 

// REMOVE INDEX.PHP AND REIDIRECT TO ROOT DIRECTORY //  
# IN ALL DIRECTORIES (EVEN IN SUB DIRECTORIES)
# RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
# ONLY WHEN ON ROOT
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s+/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1? [L,R=301,NC,NE]

// REMOVE HOME REWRITE FROM MAGENTO //  
RewriteRule ^home/?$ /? [R=301,L,NC]

// ADD WWW TO NONE WWW FOR BOTH HTTPS AND NONE HTTPS // 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

// REDIRECT ALL .HTML FILES AND ALL .HTML/ FILES WITH TRAILING SLASH // 
RewriteRule ^google[0-9a-f]+.html$ - [L]
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule (.+)\.html\/$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

// ADD TRAILING SLASH //
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

// CHECK IF REDIRECT POINTS TO A VALID FILE ##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

// REWRITE EVERYTHING ELSE TO INDEX.PHP //
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine both `http->https` and `non-www->www` rules in one single 301 redirect rule like this:

```
# // REDIRECT main domain to HTTPS and add www //
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?!www\.)[^.]+\.domain\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.tld$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.tld%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# redirect sub domains to non http
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)[^.]+\.domain\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava Almost works. It works perfect for the domain that I setup with your rule above, but all other domains (Magento stores) are redirecting back to this domain also?

Comment: Do you want to avoid redirecting `http->https` for sub domains?

Comment: Yes that's correct. This should only be valid for one domain, out of 5 domains in total, on the same server. If possible, I also want to redirect all the other domains to none https.

Comment: Thanks again. Should I delete the old www rule, when adding this one? The rule below the rewrite for home, in the original question?

Comment: Yes delete old `non-www->www` and old `http->https` rules.

Comment: Now I got a to many redirects warning from the browser. Strange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60374/discussion-between-alldo-and-anubhava).

Comment: Sorry I am unable to chat at present. These rules definitely work independently, most likely you still have some conflicting rule. Open Firebug and see what redirects are happening in Net tab.

Comment: This is what I got, it keeps redirecting between http to https over and over again:

http ://www.domain.tld

301 Moved Permanently

https ://www.domain.tld/

301 Moved Permanently

http ://www.domain.tld/

301 Moved Permanently

https ://www.domain.tld/

Comment: ok just make sure these 2 rules are just below `RewriteEngine On` line .

Comment: I just found out a typo mistake in 2nd rule. It is corrected now, please try again.

Comment: Still doesn't work, right now, all other domains are being 301-redirected to the default root domain. domain2.tld => domain.tld and domain3.tld => domain.tld and so on. Maybe this doesn't work?

Comment: These 2 rules are 100% working in my testing so make sure you test them independently first and then keep adding your other rules one by one. Needless to say that you need to clear browser cache every time. (or change 301 to 302)

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with Magentos own SSL-setup. The setting in the admin area is `Use Secure URLs in Frontend = Yes` and `Unsecure Base URL = https://www.domain.tld/` and `Secure Base URL = https://www.domain.tld/`. Need to do some more testing i think.

Comment: Yes I don't have magento to test it but outside it works pretty well. You can just comment out 2nd rule completely and concentrate on main domain first.